Looker Studio how to do a SUMIF of views based on string contained in a URL
I want to produce a metric that is number of views of pages that contain a specific string in the URL. I need this to be a metric rather than a filtered scorecard as I would like to use this metric to then calculate a conversion rate. I can do this in Excel or PowerBi but keen to get it working in Looker Studio as this is much more shareable.
| url | views |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-1 | 12000 |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-1/pricing | 4000 |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-2 | 14000 |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-2/pricing | 6000 |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-3 | 17000 |
| www.exampleurl.com/category-3/pricing | 5000 |
So I would like to output the metric 'Pricing Page views' based on any url that contains the string 'pricing' and it would equal 15000.  I have successfully achieved the number using a scorecard and a filter. However I then can't use this metric in other calculations. I want to be able to divide total views  (eg 58000) by Pricing page view to get my conversion rate 15000 / 58000 = 25.8%.
I've tried using
CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(page path, 'pricing') THEN views
    ELSE 0
END

but it won't work as I'm mixing dimensions and metrics.
If I create a count
CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(page path, 'pricing') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END

I can't work out how to do SUM IF to calculate the views. I feel like I've hit a bit of a brick wall, but feel it must be possible given I can create the scorecard + filter version. If anyone has any bright ideas I would be very grateful for the help. I've spent half a day now researching online and can't seem to find an answer.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!
To make things easier I would first create a new field called "category" and define it like this:
CASE
    WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(url, 'pricing') THEN 'pricing'
    ELSE 'other'
END

Then you can create a new field called "share_of_pricing" and use the following formula:
sum(if(category='pricing', views, 0)) / sum(views)

This field you can use in your Scorecard.
Hope this helps!
